# Android database SQlite sum() is not working in my case?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, aggregate-functions

I don't get what is wrong with my code please help me here

```
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT SUM(" +COLUMN_AMOUNT+ ") FROM "+TABLE_NAME+";";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            double monthlyTotal = 0.110;
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                monthlyTotal = cursor.getDouble(0);// get final total
            }
            else
                monthlyTotal = 0.110;
```

I am always getting monthlyTotal = 0.0, even I have initialised it to 0.110

Please check whether my onCrete() code is right or not

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

String CREATE_MONTHS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INT, " + COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " DOUBLE, " + COLUMN_REASON + " TEXT" + ");";
db.execSQL(CREATE_MONTHS_TABLE);

}
```

Comment: nothing wrong with your code!are sure you have any row in your table?

Comment: yeah I am sure because I used getCount() to check whether getCount()<= 0 and it returned false that is getCount()>0. So I think I can assume that row is available in my DB.

Comment: check your COLUMN_AMOUNT column of the table and print all rows maybe sth wrong! and change SUM(...) to sum(...). I know SQL is not CS but do it for sure!

Comment: Hey actually, I am new to android programming so can u please express what u said with code it will be great to me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you defined `COLUMN_AMOUNT` as **TEXT**. Therefore, no aggregate function can be executed on that data type.

Comment: add your table scheme to your question

Comment: Nup ModularSynth, `COLUMN_AMOUNT` is defined as **DOUBLE**

Comment: Add your insertion code because the problem is probably in the values

Comment: Maybe it **was** originally defined as TEXT. Then you **changed** it to DOUBLE, but you forgot to uninstall and reinstall your app

Answer (score 0):

When you call `getCount()` on the cursor, you will always get `1`, because the `SUM()` function will always return a result, even if the original set is empty:

```
sqlite> create table t(x);
sqlite> select sum(x) from t;
sum(x)    
----------
```

(In this case, `SUM()` returns `NULL`, which `getDouble()` converts to `0.0`.)

Furthermore, `SUM()` will attempt ot compute a sum from non-numbers:

```
sqlite> insert into t values('hello');
sqlite> select sum(x) from t;
sum(x)    
----------
0.0
```

So the problem is the data in the table (or the lack of it).
To check the number of rows in the table, use a query without `SUM()`; use `COUNT()`, or [queryNumEntries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

Comment: But my primary moto is to get sum of  `COLUMN_AMOUNT`  so, when i was not getting sum i used `getCount()` to check whether it returns the count or not so that i can confirm data is entered in DB or not.

Answer (score -3):

Using String executions may not be the best way to query as its more error prone try this instead:-

```
cursor = db.query(database.Tablename, new String[]{"SUM(" + 
database.columname + ")"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Please abstain from throwing in **random guesses**. Both `query()` and `rawQuery()` work perfectly.

Comment: Yes you'r right I removed the last sentence .I just showed him a better way to it.

Comment: You should also remove the first sentence as well.

Comment: My ego doesn't let me :) .Its useful to the people who need it.

Comment: Isn't using android methods less error prone and more clear than using  execSQL statements  ? .At least you don't have to adjust the spaces .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150524/discussion-between-omar-ahmed-and-modularsynth).

Comment: Well, in a certain sense, yes. But I'm so used to SQL syntax for 20+ years, and I really prefer using `rawQuery()` and `execSQL()`, since it gives me more control.

Comment: :) My point...> Its useful to the people who need it. Thats all what the rating is about.